# how to trigger new job by comment in Pull Request for GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

Let's say that I have a workflow:

```yaml
---
name: 'DEV Test'

on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created]
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - 'develop'

defaults:
  run:
    shell: python

jobs:
  test:
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    if: ${{ (github.event_name == 'issue_comment' && github.event.issue.pull_request && startsWith(github.event.comment.body, 'continue_even_if_fail')) || github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}
    name: 'DEV Test'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check if specific directives exists
        env:
          PR_MSG: ${{ github.event.pull_request.body }}
          PR_COMMENT: ${{ github.event.comment.body }}
        run: |
          from os import environ

          global_envs_file = environ.get('GITHUB_ENV')

          # if event type is comment get message from comment body
          if '${{ github.event_name }}' == 'issue_comment':
            msg = environ.get('PR_COMMENT', '')
          # if event type is PR create or sync get message from PR message
          else:
            msg = environ.get('PR_MSG', '')

          # set global ENV `CONTINUE` to 0 or 1 depending on 'continue_even_if_fail' existance
          with open(global_envs_file, 'a') as f:
            if 'continue_even_if_fail' in msg:
              f.write('CONTINUE=1\n')
            else:
              f.write('CONTINUE=0\n')

      - name: fail
        if: ${{ env.CONTINUE == 0 }}
        uses: actions/github-script@v3
        with:
          script: |
              core.setFailed('Set to fail')

      - name: complete
        run: |
          print('''
          ${{ toJSON(github) }}
          ''')
```

So if we have `continue_even_if_fail` identifier in message or PR comment, workflow should end successfully in theory. In other way it will fail (again in theory)

＊It is just a synthetic simplified example and actual logic is more complicated and meaningful

#### Problem

This workflow works correctly if I update or create Pull Request. But nothing happens if I add comment to PR conversation.

#### Question

How to trigger test job in PR that will successfully end by new specific comment with `continue_even_if_fail` message

#### PS

even if I simplify condition

from

```
if: ${{ (github.event_name == 'issue_comment' && github.event.issue.pull_request && startsWith(github.event.comment.body, 'continue_even_if_fail')) || github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}
```

to

```
if: ${{ github.event_name == 'issue_comment' || github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}
```

Nothing will be triggered

Documentation that I used to create the workflow: [about events](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/events/github-event-types#pullrequestreviewcommentevent), [about triggers](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows), [especially about `issue_comment` trigger](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#issue_comment-on-issues-only-or-pull-requests-only), [about `issue_comment` in Japanese](https://buildersbox.corp-sansan.com/entry/2021/02/05/110000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was obvious but not intuitive at same time. So, I decided to share cause as answer.

Let's imagine that you have three branches: `feature`, `develop`, `main`. Where `main` is a **default** branch.
And now you trying to do Pull Request `feature` → `develop`.

The import point is that `issue_comment` is always triggered under default branch (`main` in my case). But `pull_request` is triggered under Pull Request's branch (merged version of `feature` and `develop` in my case)

It means that `run_test.yaml` workflow **should exists in default branch `main`** to be triggered by `issue_comment`. In other way `pull_request` will be triggered if `run_test.yaml` workflow exists in `feature` or `develop` branches.

To be able trigger both actions `issue_comment` and `pull_request` we have to add `run_test.yaml` file at `main` and `feature` (`develop`) branches first.

And that was cause in my case, because workflow file was newly created inside Pull Request and only `pull_request` event was triggered.

Here is a caution point: Because triggered branch is `main` you have to manually set PR's branch when checkout:

```yaml
steps:
    - name: "Get PR's branch name"
      id: get_branch
      run: |
        PR=$(curl -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" ${{ github.event.issue.pull_request.url }})
        echo "::set-output name=branch::$(echo $PR | jq -r '.head.ref')"

    - name: "Checkout"
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        ref: ${{ steps.get_branch.outputs.branch }}
```

And here is a second problem why `issue_comment` can't be used as Pull Request internal trigger for CI tests: because it triggered under default `main` branch it runs outside of the Pull Request as separated Action. And even if it completes with success PR's last CI test still will be marked as failed (with `×` mark)

Answer (score 2):

The following workflow works very well for the described use case:

```
name: 'Analyze PR body or comment'

on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created]

  pull_request:
    branches:
      - '*'

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check if specific directives exists
        id: directive-validation
        uses: actions/github-script@v3
        with:
          script: |
            const directive = 'continue_even_if_fail';
            const payload = context.payload;

            let body = '';

            if (payload.pull_request) {
              body = payload.pull_request.body;
            } else if (payload.comment) {
              body = payload.comment.body;
            }

            return body.includes(directive);

      - name: Will fail
        uses: actions/github-script@v3
        with:
          script: |
            core.setFailed('Set to fail')

      - name: Allowed to run if the previous step succeded or the directive present
        if: success() || steps.directive-validation.outputs.result == 'true'
        run: |
          echo "Success!"
```

It uses the [GitHub Script](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-script) action only. The script already has access to the payload context.

The last step has the `if` condition. According to this condition, this step will run in case the previous step was successful or anyway if the `directive-validation` step returned `true`.

In addition, You can extend the workflow triggers to handle even a PR body update or a comment update:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - edited

  issue_comment:
    types:
      - created
      - edited
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer although the problem was inside my environment and lack of workflows understanding